# How do I renename a Bluetooth device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to rename a Bluetooth device from a Windows Phone 8 app. I know the AT commands to send to the device but i belive I connecto to the device somhow wrong.

I have an old PDA program that can rename my device, and that program is the source of my AT commands som I'm pretty sure they are correct.

If I start a Datalogger and rename my device from my PDA no data appears in the log, if I do the same from my phone I get all the commands in my Datalogger.

Here is how I connect to my device in my windows phone App:

```
public void Rename()
{
    var info = GetPeerInfo();
   /*
      GetPeerInfo() gives me the PeerInformation of my device and it works as expected.
   */

    if (info == null)
        return;

    socket = new StreamSocket();

    Task.Run(async () => { await socket.ConnectAsync(info.HostName, "1"); }).Wait();

    var dataWriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);

    /*
       Note 
         "to" is an internal class containg the new name of my bluetooth device, its bluetooth config etc.
         "newLaneNumber" is an integer indicading a postfix to the new name 
    */

    UpdateDisplayName(dataWriter, to, newLaneNumber);

    Task.Run(async () => { await dataWriter.StoreAsync();  }).Wait();
    socket.Dispose();
    socket = null;

    return;
}
```

This is the method sending the AT commands

```
    private void UpdateDisplayName_Other(DataWriter dataWriter, InspectionTester newDisplayname, int newLaneNumber)
    {
        //Login
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
        dataWriter.WriteString("///");
        Thread.Sleep(6000);

        var bluetoothDefault = new string[]
        {
            "AT*AGLC=0,1",
            "AT*AGCM=2,1",
            "AT*AGDM=3,1",
            "AT*AGPM=2,1", // pairable (not pairable: "AT*AGPM=1,1")
            "AT*AGFP="+'"'+"0"+'"'+",1",
            "AT*AGSM=1,1",
            "AT*ADDSP=0,1",
            "AT*AGMSP=1,1",
            "AT*ADDCP=255,1",
            "AT*ADNRP=0,1",
            "AT*AMSIT=1,1",
            "AT*AMET=5000,5000,1",
            "AT*AMLP=0,0,1",
            "AT*AMMP=255,1",
            "AT*AMWFM=1,6,1",
            "AT*AMPM=1,1",
            "AT*ACCB=1,1",
            "AT*AMDS=1,1,1",
            "AT*AMWS=0,0,0,0,0,1"
        };

        var tmpString = string.Empty;

        foreach (var element in bluetoothDefault)
        {
            tmpString = element + "\r";
            dataWriter.WriteString(tmpString);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        //Name
        tmpString = "AT*AGLN=\"" + to.BluetoothName + newLaneNumber.ToString("D2") + "\",1\r";
        dataWriter.WriteString(tmpString);
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        //Baudrate
        tmpString = "AT*AMRS=" + to.BluetoothConfig + "\r";
        dataWriter.WriteString(tmpString);

        //Logout
        tmpString = "AT*AMWS=0,0,0,0,1,0\r";
        dataWriter.WriteString(tmpString);
    }
```

Some where  I'm doing something wrong, I belive I connect the wrong way but I can't find any information about how else to do it.

Here is a log taken from an update attempt from the phone :

```
///AT*AGLC=0,1
AT*AGCM=2,1
AT*AGDM=3,1
AT*AGPM=2,1
AT*AGFP="0",1
AT*AGSM=1,1
AT*ADDSP=0,1
AT*AGMSP=1,1
AT*ADDCP=255,1
AT*ADNRP=0,1
AT*AMSIT=1,1
AT*AMET=5000,5000,1
AT*AMLP=0,0,1
AT*AMMP=255,1
AT*AMWFM=1,6,1
AT*AMPM=1,1
AT*ACCB=1,1
AT*AMDS=1,1,1
AT*AMWS=0,0,0,0,0,1
AT*AGLN="BMGTMGA1-01",1
AT*AMRS=5,1,2,2,2,1,1
AT*AMWS=0,0,0,0,1,0
```

If you need some more information please say so.

Answer (score -1):

1point: most of the device don,t support the rename. Some of them just support it by saving the infomation in the RAM ,not the flash or EEPROM .

Comment: It does support rename!